# tell highest sum of two variable in two different dataset

Tags: sas

dataset jan like this

```
cc spend 
1   100
11  200
12  550
13  100
14  200
```

dataset feb like this

```
cc spend 
1   100
11  200
12  550
13  100
```

in this we have to find which month is sales higher dataset jan or  dataset feb.first we have to calculate the sum of spend in jan & sum of spend in feb then find which is higher.

i try this code

```
data jantotal;
set jan;
sum spend;
run;

data febtotal;
set feb;
sum spend;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your endgame is, e.g. do you want to select one dataset over the other Or do you just want a summary of which month had the highest sales.

You could start by doing something like this with proc sql, which creates an output dataset `total` with each month and the sum of spend.

```
proc sql;
  create table total as 
   select "Jan" as month, sum(spend) as total
    from jan
     group by month
      UNION
    select "Feb" as month, sum(spend) as total
     from feb
      group by month;
quit;
```

If you provide more information as to what your final output should be I can provide more useful code.

Comment: i just want the summary of which month has highest sale with sas code not use of sql

Comment: proc sql is sas code. The above proc code will run in sas. Or were you looking for a data step? Is there a reason you want to use a data step?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
data jantotal;
  set jan end=last;
  retain sum 0; /* this line is optional */
  sum + spend;
  if last;
  month = "jan";
  drop spend cc;
run;

data febtotal;
  set feb end=last;
  retain sum 0; /* this line is optional */
  sum + spend;
  if last;
  month = "feb";
  drop spend cc;
run;
```

After that you should concatenate datasets:

```
data total;
  set jantotal febtotal;
run;
```

And sort result:

```
proc sort data=total out=total_sorted;
  by descending sum;
run;
```

I would like to create here some macro programs to automatize process of writing this program. This solution is almost the same (in result) as @Huw, but the code is longer and is using a datasteps instead of sql.